# a proof about closable operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I am self-studying the chapter of closed and closable operators. I have the following problem which I cannot find its proof.

Let $A$ be a closable operator and denote by $B$ a closed extension. We call $\bar{A}$ the closure of the (closable) operator $A.$ It is the smallest closed extension of $A$ in the sense that if $A\subset B$ and $B$ is closed, then $\bar{A}\subset B.$

Could anyone help with a proof? (I can guess this, but not sure what to prove...)

Comment: It is the definition of closure of an operator

Comment: How to define the closure of operator, could you please express that mathematically?

Comment: As the smallest closed extension in the sense that you wrote. How do you define it?

Comment: You could also take the closure of the graph of $A $ in $X \times Y $, where $A:X'\to Y $ and $X'\leq X $. If this closure is a graph of a linear operator, call this operator $\overline {A} $.

Comment: you mean, the closure of $A$ can be defined as the smallest closed extension of $A$ in the sense that if $A\subset B$ and $B$ is closed?

Comment: @math101 yes, this is the common definition of it.